# AJAX vs HTTPRequest

Tags: c#, ajax, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, httprequest

i'm rewriting WebAppication to Native Application on Windows Phone.

I got into a little trouble, can't post data.

Here is the code for WebApplication - it works:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://blabla.blabla.com/mobile-api/v1/security',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        // data: JSON.stringify ({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params":["TestLogin", "SuperPass"], "id": 1}),
        data: JSON.stringify({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params":[username, password], "id": 1}),  
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data){
            callback.onSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            callback.onError(xhr.status);
        }
    });
```

And here is my C# code:

```
private void PostLoginData()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://blabla.blabla.com/mobile-api/v1/security");
        request.Method="POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback),request);
    }
    void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        // End the stream request operation
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

        // Create the post data
        string postData = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"login\", \"params\":{\"username\":" + "\"TestLogin\"" + ", \"password\":" + "\"SuperPass\"" + "}, \"id\": 1}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Add the post data to the web request
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the web request
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }
    void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
        using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //For debug: show results
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            });
        }
    }
```

Response returns me:

Invalid method parameters.

If i try to post Login and Password without "", like so:

```
string postData = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"login\", \"params\":{\"username\":" + "TestLogin" + ", \"password\":" + "SuperPass" + "}, \"id\": 1}";
```

Response is:

Parse error

**Login and Password are 100% correct... problem i think is in the post data, because the WebApplications request works**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct string should be:

```
string postData = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"login\", \"params\":[" + "\""+Username+"\"" + "," + "\""+UserPassword+"\"" + "], \"id\": 1}";
```